@AssistedInject with @HiltWorker doesn't work after gradle update
After some dependency updates (incl. version of gradle and kotlin) old code isn't compile anymore in release build
There is error

error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] b.a cannot be provided without an
@Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

Code:
@HiltWorker
class PeriodicReminderWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    private val reminderProcessor: ReminderProcessor
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        reminderProcessor.invoke(forceUpdateReminders = true)
        return Result.success()
    }
}

In old branch everything works as before. In current works as well in debug build
Gradle has been updated from 8.3.2 to 8.7.1
Kotlin - from 2.0.10 to 2.0.21
gradle wrapper - from 8.6 to 8.9
